# About ListBox limit item

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, listbox

***Hello everyone,I am new here, can I ask a question:***

- Let's say I have a ListBox (with more than 5k items of all English words ). and a richTextBox.
- And a ListBox usually load every items, right? How can I change my ListBox to just load/pick a few (maybe 10 items) from the data?

***EXAMPLE:***

**When a user type a word, I dont want my ListBox to load every thing starting with the word my user input. I just want my ListBox to load just a few item.(More to like a word prediction software) **

**Please give an answer that is not too complicated, since I am a beginner.**

Thanks, Teik Fai.

Comment: First, you didn't read the stackoverflow rules as e.g. your question title is not expressive at all. Second, your question is a bit confusing, state a understandable example. Third, show us what you have so far, we are not a programming service.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your question, it looks like you need to implement virtualization on the listbox.

You can either use a `VirtualizingStackPanel` inside a `Listbox` as `ItemsPanel` Template or you use - `ItemsControl` and set its property `VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`

This should help.